# PayPal IPN file_get_contents('php://input') works in sandbox but not with live system

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I have been struggling to get PayPal IPN working. I have a simple 'buy it now' button and a very basic php script that receives the message. At this stage I don't do anything with the received data just to get the communication established. In sandbox environment it all works as it should. The moment I switch to the live system the validation of the message always fails. After a bit of debugging and logging I nailed it down to one line in my ipn.php script.

```
file_get_contents('php://input')
```

in sandbox environment this call returns proper transaction data. In live environment however it returns some kind of binary data or just garbage.

currently I'm using this script:
https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN
(updated to log and use ssl 4)
I tried a few other solutions with the same result.
it doesn't matter if I use ssl, curl or any of the combinations it never receives the correct data from PayPal. I use real transaction data and just re-send messages from my PayPal account to test it.

```
public function processIpn($post_data=null) {

    $encoded_data = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

    if ($post_data === null) { 
        // use raw POST data 
        if (!empty($_POST)) {
            $this->post_data = $_POST;
            $encoded_data .= '&'.file_get_contents('php://input');
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "encoded data: $encoded_data ". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        } else {
            throw new Exception("No POST data found.");
        }
    }
```

my modified code above logs the received data to a file and I get results like this:

```
encoded data: cmd=_notify-validate&�n%�
```

Am I supposed to treat data from live PayPal differently to sandbox? Obviously if I sent that garbage back to PayPal it returns INVALID response.
Because it worked in sandbox I don't think it is my sever issue (dreamhost). I tired some php settings recommended from other posts anyway just to be sure:

```
ini_set("allow_url_fopen", true);
```

but so far nothing helped.
any hints as to what try next very welcome :-)

Comment: I'm having the same issue - wondering if its an internal paypal error. Just can't get any of my IPNs to validate today

Comment: it seems that messages resent manually from PayPal are broken. I just went through my own checkout again using my wife's account and ipn worked flawlessly. Then I re sent that transaction from PayPal history and it was broken. 2 days of poking and reading about and it is a bug on PayPal side...

Comment: if you resend IPN from paypal, it will have the same parameters as before (seems logic though wasted a lot of my time), if you made changes meanwhile, even changed the default encoding on paypal, it wont take it into account